# Standard Windows Server 2019 wizard setup with AD, DNS & DHCP does not resolve any DHCP client names

Tags: active-directory, dhcp-server, windows-server-2019, nslookup, dns-server

I am working myself through learning and setting up a pretty standard Windows Server 2019 (Essentials edition) serving as an AD PDC, DNS- & DHCP server for a very small network. I followed some guides (like [this one](https://www.dskoli.in/blog/install-active-directory-with-dhcp-on-windows-server-2019) or [this one](https://www.moderndeployment.com/windows-server-2019-active-directory-installation-beginners-guide/)) to get through the various steps. I have configured a static IPv4 address (disabled IPv6), added AD, DNS and DHCP roles, configured AD (following the wizard with basic defaults), added a reverse lookup zone to DNS and authorized and configured DHCP with an initial scope.

Clients are able to obtain IP addresses and can nslookup/resolve external names (like serverfault.com) as well as the server itself.

However, neither the server, nor any of the clients can nslookup/resolve any of the client names. They do show up as leases in the DHCP zone with what I believe are proper names (like winclient.DOMAIN.XXX), but nslookup returns

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.2.1    (<-this is the server's IP address)

*** localhost can't find winclient: Non-existent domain
```

The only difference on the server is that it shows Server: localhost and Address: 127.0.0.1.

I am totally lost as to what could be wrong - specifically as I am pretty sure that I did follow the guides and did not add anything myself.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guides you link don't seem to configure DHCP+DNS to cooperate for dynamic DNS updates.

The way to do this:

**Define a user in whose context the DHCP server will run**

Simply add a domain user with no special rights, and give it a properly strong password. Then open the DHCP management console, right-click the protocol you want to change (IPv4 or IPv6), and select Properties and the Advanced tab. Click Credentials and enter the relevant information for the account.

**Tell DHCP to always attempt to update DNS records**

In the same properties window, select the DNS tab. Ensure the following choices are ticked:

`Enable DNS Dynamic Updates(…)` -> `Always dynamically update DNS records`
`Dynamically update DNS records for DHCP clients that do not request updates`

**Set correct DHCP server AD group membership**

The DHCP server(s) should exist in the group `DNSUpdateProxy`. No other user or computer accounts may exist in this group.

Comment: This was the right hint. I had to tell DHCP to always update DNS records - apparently because I have clients on the network that are not part of the domain.

Comment: Why would I want to define a user in whose context the DHCP server will run? For me, not doing it still resolved the issue. Added security? Any feature I am missing?

Comment: Yes, it's for added security. Otherwise the DHCP server runs as Local System, which provides he service with unnecessarily high privileges.

Comment: Oh yes: It's probably functional too: If you run your DHCP server on a separate machine from your AD/DNS (which is recommended for larger setups, again for security reasons), Local System on the DHCP server might not be allowed to ask DNS on a different machine to update.